# Why does Mercurial only have one level of rollback?

Tags: mercurial, rollback

I understand the restrictions of rollback and the [care required in its use](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#rollback), but I just wondered why there is only *one* level of rollback.

My guess it's a design decision and that the hassle of storing multiple previous transactional states to handle multiple levels of rollback is more trouble than its worth.

Comment: From my understanding, your guess is pretty well accurate. The mercurial way is 'everything is immutable' .. so if you need to roll back something you committed 8 revisions ago, the 'hg' way is to introduce a new change that does it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's only one level of rollback because rollback was never really intended as a feature.  Rollback exists, and has it's odd name, because it grew out of mercurial's commit/push/pull transaction system.

If a network push is coming in and it gets 99% done and then the connection is lost the repository shouldn't be left in an inconsistent state.  To make sure that an incomplete change can be discarded a "before anything happened" pointer is created before any writes are done and if the change is aborted everything is reset to that state -- rolled back.

The `rollback` command is really just "failing" the previous operation after it had successfully completed.  It's just something that "came free" after necessary transactional security was designed in.

When using something like a [controlling hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) one can define checks/tests that must be passed in order for a push or commit to complete successfully.  In order to not-complete successfully it must be possible to undo that in progress commit, but that doesn't require multiple levels either.

As VonC correctly notes rollback can be pretty dangerous.  Many a person rollsback changes they've already pushed and then gets very confused when other those changes come back on subsequent pulls. The `hg backout` command is almost always a better idea.

Note also that you can simulate a rollback to any point in time easily by doing this:

```
hg clone -r last_revision_I_want repo_with_things_I_do_not_want new_repo_with_only_good_stuff
```

Answer (score 5):

The trick is: `hg rollback` is not just about resetting some commits, it reset every data and meta-data associated with the repository.
It actually has [no equivalent in Git](http://wiki.sympy.org/wiki/Git_hg_rosetta_stone), and is quite a dangerous mechanism.
It can be mis-used as a way to rewrite the history by resetting it, and that [can "reset" more than you wanted](http://rkj.github.com/Mercurial/2010/02/18/Mercurial-rollback-dataloss.html).
To allow this on more than one level back would be too dangerous.

When it comes only to [resetting/rewriting changeset](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory)  (which are, by design, immutable), [extensions like MQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) are better suited.

Comment: I agree - definitely something to avoid - I use MQ so it's never something I've had call to use. Just seems an odd limitation - if you're going to allow it at all why not allow more than one level of rollback.